# Add all users in one group to another group?

Tags: users, group

I have some users in a group called `aa` and I need to give them the rights to write to a folder which is currently `tomcat:tomcatdeploy`.

The straightforward way to do this is to add all the users to the `tomcatdeploy` group, one-by-one.

Is it possible to say that members of group `aa` are also automatically members of `tomcatdeploy` by somehow adding the `aa` group to the `tomcatdeploy` group?

Or is that trying to push the UNIX permissions scheme too far?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `lid` command to get a list of users in `aa`, and the loop over that list to add them to `tomcatdeploy`:

```
for u in $(lid -g -n aa); do usermod -a -G tomcatdeploy $u; done
```

Comment: `for u in $(lid -g -n aa); do usermod -a -G tomcatdeploy $u; done` (I suppose you meant `$u` in usermod, not just `u`)

Comment: Good catch! I just fixed the code in my answer.

Answer (score 10):

You didn't mention what platform you are on, but a Linux system from within the last 5 years (or more, probably) supports ACLs, in addition to the traditional Unix file system permissions. By using ACLs, you can add the 2nd group to the directory with write access:

```
$ setfacl -m group:2ndtomcatdeploy:rwx target_directory
```

You can use `getfacl` to display the ACLs and `ls -l` will show a '+' at the end of the usual symbolic mode string.