# Setting multiple groups as directory owners

Tags: permissions, group, subversion

On my server I have directory `/srv/svn`.

Is it possible to set this directory to have multiple group ownerships, for instance `devFirmA`, `devFirmB` and `devFirmC`?

The point is, I want to `subversion` version control manage multiple users accross multiple repositories and I do not know how to *merge* `/srv/svn`, the root directory of repositories, permissions. I have, for instance, three firms, `FirmA`, `FirmB` and `FirmC`. Now, inside `/srv/svn` I've created three directories, `FirmA`, `FirmB`, `FirmC` and inside them I've created repository for each project and now I do not know how to establish permission scheme since all elementes inside `/srv/svn` are owned by `root:root`, which is not ok, or am I wrong?

Comment: Do the firm groups access each others files? Or are they completely separate, other than sharing a parent directory?

Comment: @TechZilla firm group MUST Not access each others files, ther MUST be separated, only I must have access to all directories.

Comment: OK, I posted the correct answer, you should not use ACLs for this.  They are a last resort option, this problem is still a very common one.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is an extremely common problem, if I understand it accurately, and I encounter it constantly.  If I used ACLs for every trivial grouping problem, I would have tons of unmanageable systems. They are using the best practice when you cannot do it any other way, not for this situation.  This is the method I very strongly recommend.

First you need to set your umask to 002, this is so a group can share with itself.  I usually create a file like `/etc/profile.d/firm.sh`, and then add a test command with the umask.

`[ $UID -gt 10000 ] && umask 002`

Next you need to set the directories to their respective groups,

```
chgrp -R FirmA /srv/svn/FirmA 
chgrp -R FirmB /srv/svn/FirmB
chgrp -R FirmC /srv/svn/FirmC
```

Finally you need to set the SGID bit properly, so the group will always stay to the one you set.  This will prevent a written file from being set to the writer's GID.

```
find /srv/svn/FirmA -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 2775
find /srv/svn/FirmB -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 2775
find /srv/svn/FirmC -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 2775

find /srv/svn/FirmA -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 664
find /srv/svn/FirmB -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 664
find /srv/svn/FirmC -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 664
```

Now finally if you want to prevent the directories from being accessed by other users.

```
chmod 2770 /srv/svn/FirmA
chmod 2770 /srv/svn/FirmB
chmod 2770 /srv/svn/FirmC
```

Comment: Warning: this should work but removes execution permission bit on all files. This is okay if your directory tree only holds documents. If it contains executable files this will prevent execution, which may ruin your setup.

Comment: This might be also a nice idea, but does not answer the question at all.

Comment: This as described only partitions the three folders so that only members of each firm can modify only their respective files - it does not give 'svn' the access it needs.

Comment: This is very close though.  What's missing is to give _you_ access to all the groups.  

Add this step, assuming your login is `svnadmin`:  

    `sudo usermod -a -G FirmA,FirmB,FirmC svnadmin`

This will add `svnadmin` to all of these groups.  Since the files in all these groups have 'group write' enabled (`chmod 664` did this), you, plus firmX, will be the only writers of files owned by firmX.

Comment: Actually you could go another route altogether - do the steps above partitioning permissions only to members of the respective groups, and then set up the `sudo` permissions for `svnadmin` so that `svnadmin` is able to change group on the fly - with this you could for example rename FirmC files like this: `sudo -g FirmC mv FirmC_fileA FirmC_fileB`

Comment: Finally, addressing the comment left by @StéphaneGourichon (good catch) - you could change the "find -type f" commands to run a script which checks for and preserves "execution permissions", instead of just doing a fixed `chmod`, on each file.

Comment: Better - change the permissions to add/subtract what you want to add/subtract - e.g. do `find /srv/svn/FirmA -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod ug+rw,o+r,o-wx`

Comment: @richp, Absolutly correct Rich, you just add users into the firm groups you want them to be able to access/modify.

Answer (score 49):

You can only have one group as *owner*.

However using [**access control lists**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/acl.5.html) you can define permissions for other groups.

Check if you have ACL installed issuing the command `getfacl`. 
 If your system hasn't ACL installed, install the command line tools which are in the [`acl` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/acl) with: `sudo apt-get install acl`

With [`getfacl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/getfacl.1.html) you can read the ACL information of a directory or other file, and with [`setfacl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/setfacl.1.html) you can add groups to a file.

For example:

```
setfacl -m g:devFirmB:rwx /srv/svn/
```

Adds the group `devFirmB` with **r**ead, **w**rite, e**x**ecute permissions to directory `/srv/svn`.

If you also want files created in that directory to be owned by multiple groups, set the ACL as the default ACL. The `X` in the default group entry means “allow execution if executable by the owner (or anyone else)”.

```
setfacl -m g:devFirmB:rwx /srv/svn/  
setfacl -d -m g:devFirmB:rwX /srv/svn/
```

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to have a file owned by multiple Linux groups with traditional Unix permissions. (However, [it is possible with ACL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/195470).)

But you might use the following workaround and create a new group (e.g. called `devFirms`) which will include all users of the groups `devFirmA`, `devFirmB` and `devFirmC`.
You create new user groups with:

```
sudo addgroup NEWGROUPNAME
```

First, you might have to install `id-utils` to get the `lid`-command:

```
sudo apt-get install id-utils
```

Then you can run the following line of code to easily copy all users of `SOURCEGROUP` to `TARGETGROUP`. Of course you have to run the command once for each group you want to copy. Don't forget to replace the capitalized place-holders with the actual group names.

```
for u in $(lid -g -n SOURCEGROUP); do sudo usermod -a -G TARGETGROUP $u; done
```

So in your case you would have to run the command (all lines at once):

```
sudo addgroup devFirms &&
for u in $(lid -g -n devFirmA); do sudo usermod -a -G devFirms $u; done &&
for u in $(lid -g -n devFirmB); do sudo usermod -a -G devFirms $u; done &&
for u in $(lid -g -n devFirmC); do sudo usermod -a -G devFirms $u; done
```

Note that these commands only copy all users who are *current* members of the source groups. Every user who gets added later will also have to be manually added to your common group with the `adduser` command. Just replace once again the capitalized place-holders with the actual user and group name (`devFirms`):

```
sudo adduser NEWUSER TARGETGROUP
```

<sub>Thanks to [Justin Ethier](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3635/justin-ethier) for his answer at [Unix&Linux.SE: Add all users of one group to another group?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8141/103151)</sub>

Comment: @Gilles do you thing your scheme would work for Subversion server multiple repositories with multiple users as in my update of question?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible.

Each file (and so also directories) can only have one user and one group.

Comment: Providing an alternative approach to get the same or a similar result would be nice.

Comment: -1, file can have multiple groups using ACL

Answer (score 3):

In order to provide different rights to multiple groups or users use the following commands (Tested on RHEL 6 & 7):

To make new owner of group:

```
setfacl -m g:<group_name>:<rights you want to give eg.rwx> -R <directory_name>
```

To check current acl settings:

```
getfacl <directory_name>
```

Comment: Tested, works on Ubuntu 16.04.3 too