# Adding group permission to directory without changing group ownership?

Tags: linux

I have a directory called "music" and two groups: music, singers.

I executed

```
chgrp music music
```

I am looking to grant read and write access to the /music directory for the singers group, but I don't want to change the ownership.

Is this possible?

I am a bit confused with chown and chgrp. I believe chown changes ownership for a single user and not a group? and chgrp changes the group?

Is there a way to set group ownership, but grant permissions to one other specified group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do this using traditional permissions, but it can be done using the `getfacl` and `setfacl` commands (typically available via the `acl` package).

[`getfacl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/getfacl.1.html) allows you to read the ACL entries for a directory or file.

[`setfacl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/setfacl.1.html) allows changing the ACL entries for a directory or file.

In your example, you would want to run something like the following commands:

```
setfacl -m g:music:rwx /path/to/music
setfacl -m g:singers:rwx /path/to/music
```

`-m` to `modify`, `g` to modify the group ACL(s), `music` and `singers` the group name, `rwx` the traditional permissions you want applied, `/path/to/music` the path to the directory you want to modify ACLs for.

To make this apply by default to any new files/directories created within the music folder, you want to add the `-d` flag for `default`, and to apply recursively to all existing files/directories, you want to add the `-R` flag for `recursive`.

Answer (score 1):

`chown` changes the user and/or group ownership of each given file. `chgrp` only changes the group of the files specified. Usually, you can run `man <command>` (if it has a manual) or `<command --help>` to see how a command is to be used.

So the command `chgrp music music` would give the group `music` ownership of the folder `music`.

Its not possible for multiple groups to own a file or folder, but there are workarounds:

- Assuming group `music` owns the folder, you can use an [ACL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/195470) to define permissions group`singers`.
- Create a new group which will include all users of groups `singers` and `music` and set that make that new group owner of the folder `music` which is discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/195478).